# How to link with other pages?

Tags: silverlight

I have tried, but only work with webpages on the Internet.
How to link with other pages within a file?

```
<HyperlinkButton Background="#00FF0000" Height="46" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,0,0,93" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="134" BorderBrush="Red" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="26.667" Foreground="Red" Content="Next Page" NavigateUri="C:\SilverlightApplication15\SilverlightApplication15\try.xaml">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <ic:HyperlinkAction/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </HyperlinkButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this .xaml file is in your xap, try using the relative path instead:

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/try.xaml">
```

Also, this may help: [Using the HyperlinkButton Control](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Using-the-HyperlinkButton-control-in-Silverlight-2-Beta-1.aspx)